# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect login details were provided

Tags: javascript, discord

I have code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content == "ping"){
        message.reply("pong")
    }
});

client.login('SECRET BOT TOKEN HERE')
```

But i also have error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Incorrect login details were provided.

Comment: Maybe you should provide a correct login detail then?

Comment: It's correct login detail

Comment: Most likely it is saying that your token is incorrect, did you confirm that you had the correct token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that you are providing the incorrect value for the login method to connect to the Discord API, if you are using the snowflake token directly in the method, please make sure it is wrapped in quotes, if you are using something such as environment variables, please make sure you have them set up correctly and then that the values aren't returning an undesirable value. If you have exhausted these options, please return to your Discord Developers console, and make sure the token is correct.